# Чому середа кривиться на п'ятницю?

Tags: етимологія, словосполучення

Серед інтернетів зустрічаю [повсюдно розтиражоване] таке пояснення фразеологізму "[кривитися, як середа на п'ятницю](http://sum.in.ua/s/p.jatnycja)":

> Раніше в середу і п’ятницю не їли скоромного, тобто молочного і м’ясного. У п’ятницю постили суворіше, ніж у середу. От тому і кривиться середа на п’ятницю, бо їй заздрісно.

Одному мені це пояснення здається алогічним?

Заздрити тому, хто має суворіше постувати? Якщо ж тут йдеться про те, хто святіший, то чи не є заздрість гріхом?

То чому ж середа кривиться?

Comment: Те що заздрість є гріхом - цілком логічно. Навряд чи "кривиться як..." кажуть про людину у позитивному смислі. Тобто "як середа грішить, так і людина що кривится - також грішить".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Щось у цьому є:

> П'ятницю вважають достойнішим пісним днем, як середу ("Приповідки або
>   українсько-народня філософія" В.С. Плавюка, 1946)

Так от: і середа, і п'ятниця в українській свідомості були "жіночими", "пісними", "нещасливими" днями. І в середу, і в п'ятницю не можна було прясти, чесати волосся, а особливо прати і пекти хліб, і, звісно, співати й розважатися - бо ж пісні дні. Образи Середи і П'ятниці дуже подібні: обидві супроводжували небіжчика в потойбіччя, обидві асоціювалися з дівчатами (жінками), які поночі відвідували жінок, стежили за дотриманням неписаних законів і карали "порушниць" страшними карами типу зіпсованого тіста, почорнілої дитини тощо. Як на мене, єдина різниця - п'ятницю шанують більше (страстний день Христових мук), отож піст був суворішим і заборон було більше. Джерело: "[100 найвідоміших образів української міфології](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=KEoqAQAAMAAJ&q=100%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2&dq=100%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNuNmhgaLSAhWjIpoKHdCIBPQQ6AEIHTAA)".

Далі *суто авторська інтерпретація*: середа - день, коли Христа віддано під суд, але п'ятниця - день страти - безперечно значно сакральніший, урочистіший, тож і заборон має бути більше. Усе скоромне, чого не можна людині, отримує П'ятниця. До того ж, існував звичай вшановувати "святу П'ятінку": звечора залишати на столі хліб-сіль, юшку чи кашу. Середу так не вшановували, тож їй нічого не лишалося окрім як тихо заздрити й кривитися.

Answer (score 5):

Добру відповідь дав пан Дмитро на форумі [СЛОВНИК.НЕТ](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=4287):

> Здається, так кажуть не тим, що вони четверга не поділили, а тим, що і
>   середа, і п'ятниця, на відміну від четверга, — пісні дні. А кому ж до
>   вподоби постувати? От вони й кривляться (а часом і дмуться, й
>   кособочаться, й дивляться, й зирять і т. ін.) одна на одну. Див. також
>   [попісніти](http://sum.in.ua/s/popisnity).

А *попісніти* в переносному сенсі означає, стати сумним, пригніченим (див. посилання з цитати).

Хоча варіант заздрощів теж маж логічне пояснення, адже виходить, що в п'ятницю люди, типу, духовніші.